# Keep the cookies that are made on a file read still exist in the next other file read php

Tags: php, rest, curl, php-curl

So I want to do an API call with PHP from https://www.mangaeden.com/api/mymanga (I call this "first file") to retrieve my personal data (e.g. my favorite comic, etc.) in JSON format, but to do that I have to login from https://www.mangaeden.com/ajax/login/?username=xxx&password=xxx (I call this "second file"), that file contains a program for storing cookies which contains my username and password that I gave from the URL parameter.

When I run first file with cURL function to send header, the header that also contains the cookies data including my username and password is successfully sent, but after that when I call the second file to send my personal data, the cookie does not exist so my data file does not appear.

```php
function run_set_cookie_function_inside_this_file($file_url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

// if this file is executed, the user's username and password will be stored in cookies
run_set_cookie_function_inside_this_file("https://www.mangaeden.com/ajax/login/?username=xxx&password=xxx");
// this file requires user's username and password which stored in cookies to return other data (example: user's favorite movie, pet, etc.)
echo file_get_contents("https://www.mangaeden.com/api/mymanga/");
```

*Note: The 2 files (first and second files) are not mine, so I cannot change the program code inside*

That's my problem, so my question is **how do I keep the cookies that are made on the first file still exist in the second file?**

Sorry for my bad English and messy sentences that difficult to understand.
Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You need to set CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE (which a bit of basic research before asking could have told you already, IMHO.)

Comment: try my latest answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.mangaeden.com/ajax/login/?username=xxx&password=xxx');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                curl_exec($ch);

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.mangaeden.com/api/mymanga/');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                $output = curl_exec($ch);
                echo $output;
                curl_close($ch)
```

I have something like this login with first curl and request api with second!